# Can I visit a hotel lobby to visit the receptionist?

Tags: hotels

I have an old friend who works at a local hotel whom I have not seen in a while.  She is the receptionist in the lobby.  Is it possible to visit her in the lobby even if I don't have a reservation?  Have people ever done that before?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.

Comment: Assuming you keep it short and don't [look suspicious](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b6/Pretty_woman_movie.jpg) it should be no problem.

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many people come into hotel lobby without reservation!

Comment: I can give an answer for the UK listing ASBO and PSO and the like, but there's no country specified. Please edit to show what country we're talking about and WHY the question is pertinent to travel and then click 'reopen' thanks

Comment: http://patch.com/florida/fort-myers/man-gets-135-years-prison-visiting-receptionist

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You don't need a reservation to do a walk-in so clearly reservations are not a pre-requisite for entering the lobby. You also don't need a reservation if you're at the hotel for a conference or if you're going to dine at a restaurant inside the hotel that's accessed through the lobby, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't imagine a short visit would be a huge problem for most hotels.  Much of the job of receptionist is about talking with people.  Of course you shouldn't distract your friend from their job, nor make it a regular thing.